# ¿Como paso un item de un listview a otro listview en android?

Tags: android, listview, app, android-listview

Tengo esta lista, que es de donde quiero pasar el item mediante el popup menu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código es este:

public class ruta1 extends Activity {

```
ListView listaruta;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ruta1);

    listaruta = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_ruta1);
    list.add("Monitor");
    list.add("Keyboard");
    list.add("Mouse");
    list.add("Mother Board");
    list.add("Hard Disk");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
    listaruta.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listaruta);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.delete_id:
            list.remove(info.position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Ahora mi pregunta es ¿Que debo poner en case para lograr añadir el item que desee a la otra listview?

Aqui esta el pop menu y su código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Un item te refieres a un valor o varios valores que tiene el listado (objeto conteniendo propiedades).

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, si me refiero a un solo valor, ahora estoy tratando con un popup menu, logre darle la opción de eliminar ese item, pero no se cual es el código a seguir para añadir un solo item de un listview a otro listview. Gracias por la guía.

Comment: Seria buena idea que agregaras imagenes y código de tu avance para explicar.

Comment: Ya esta, que me dices ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas en realidad es enviar un dato de un Activity en un ListView a otra Activity.

El envió de datos entre Actividades se realiza generalmente mediante un `Bundle` en el cual se agregan valores y ese `bundle` se envía a través de un `Intent` hacia la `Activity` destino, obten el valor del día al dar click en el elemento y agregalo a un bundle:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtraActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("diaListView", valorDia);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Cuando cargues la `Activity` destino mediante [getExtras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()), recibirás el dato de esta forma:

```
String valorDia = getIntent().getExtras().getString("diaListView");
```

o simplemente mediante:

```
String valorDia = getIntent().getStringExtra("diaListView");
```